# How do I interpret answers when going backwards with transition matrices?

Tags: matrices, data-analysis, transition-matrix

I used the equation Sn=T^-1 (Sn+1 -F) to work backwards and find the previous month from a transition matrix, but my values end up being large numbers, as well as a negative value. How do I interpret these values from here?

Edit: These are the workings for further clarifications. I do not understand how to interpret these values, especially the negative result.

[image: workings]

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's not clear what's going on here, but it's quite possible that your transition matrix is [ill-conditioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number).  If so, you can't "interpret these values".